# cronjob being kill before finish

Tags: cron

I create a cronjob for periodically run the executatble compile from python.

```
20 23 * * * .../TestInno/inno_main >>.../TestInno/Log/Inno_cronlog_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log*
```

the executable consisted of 2 task

1. update database
2. sent email notification

When I run the executable in command line, it does perfectly.
however, the cronjob only does task 1 only (from log file)

Since there's few minute pause while connecting to smtp server for sending email. I suspect that the cronjob think the job's done, so kills the task.
Is it right?
If so, how to prevent it?

Comment: cronjobs have a minimal environment.  It may only be working on the terminal because of your environment.  Add `2>&1` to the end of that line to route `stderr` to that log as well.  That may help provide some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I've added into the crontab, and the output log states "Completed" at the log end. Still not execute the 2nd task.